# How to catch up with the latest block

Tags: nodeos

Why did EOS fail to catch up with the latest block since yesterday? It was always a few minutes behind  The latest block that was chased before but now can't be synchronized to the latest block and can't be transferred

Comment: Please be a bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

EOS is very CPU-intensive. In my case (16 cores, 64G RAM, NVMe SSD, 100mbps internet connection) sync from scratch using history plugin takes about a month.